# How to make div layer unselectable in jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div element as below:

```
 <div id="wrapper">Content......</div>
```

I am getting the contents of this div layer from ajax call. What i want to do is that i want to make that div unclickable, unselectable, visibility decreased and show an loading image on top of that div.
How can i do this? any suggestion

Comment: How would you make something unclickable????

Comment: if there are any anchor tags or buttons , i dont want them to be clickable

Comment: Just return false on all possible event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for a jquery package:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

With this you can render content unselectable while loading, and add the loading image ontop of it. This is supported by the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is all you need.

```
user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
```

And for the loading image above the div in the center:

CSS:

```
#loading_spinner {
  position:absolute;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:url('image/path');
  display:none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var target = $('#target'); // or this

$('body').append('<div id="loading"></div>');
$('#loading').css({
  left: ($(target).offset().left + $(target).outerWidth()/2) - ($(this).outerWidth()/2),
  top: ($(target).offset().top + $(target).outerHeight()/2) - ($(this).outerHeight()/2),
  display: 'block'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a loading image above the "Content...." with only CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"><img id="LoadingImage" src=""/><span id="content">Content......</span></div>
```

**Style**

```
#wrapper{position:relative;}
#LoadingImage{position:absolute; z-index:2; left:0px; top:0px; opacity:0.5;}
#content{position:absolute; z-index:1; left:0px; top:0px;}
```